# Specify UTC Offset instead of timezone to ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

With ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone I'm able to do the following and get back a TimeWithZone object in the correct timezone.

```
Time.current.in_time_zone('Alaska')
:> Thu, 19 Oct 2017 08:45:08 AKDT -08:00
```

Is there an equivalent method to `in_time_zone` where I can pass it the UTC Offset in seconds and get back a TimeWithZone object with the specified offset?

```
offset = -25200 # -25200 seconds == -08:00
Time.current.in_utc_offset(offset)
:> Thu, 19 Oct 2017 08:45:08 -08:00
```

Thanks in advance!

Using Rails `5.1.2` & Ruby `2.4.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is in vanilla Ruby: `#getlocal(sec)`. It is not going to give you an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` but it will give you the `Time` which you can format or do whatever you want with it, including using ActiveSupport extensions.

```
2.4.1 :016 > Time.now.getlocal(3600)
=> 2017-10-19 22:56:45 +0100 
2.4.1 :017 > Time.now.getlocal(-3600)
=> 2017-10-19 20:56:48 -0100
```

PS: -25200 is 7 hours in seconds :) -8:00 would be 28800

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I had a hard time finding it in the docs, but figured something like this existed. Super helpful.